# Optimized jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, this

I have a bit of jQuery that I would like help optimizing.

The script works fine however, if I have more than one div that wants to use the script then they get confused.

Here is the jQuery

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".anchorLink").anchorAnimate()
    });

    jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {
        settings = jQuery.extend({
            speed : 400
        }, settings);   

        return this.each(function(){
            var caller = this
            jQuery(caller).click(function (event) { 
                event.preventDefault()
                var locationHref = window.location.href
                var elementClick = jQuery(caller).attr("href")

                var destination = jQuery(elementClick).offset().top;
                jQuery("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                    window.location.hash = elementClick
                });
                return false;
            })
        })
    }
```

Here is the typical html code:

```
<div id="container1">
<ul class="Questions">
<li class="anchorLink" href="#myAnchor">
<a class="faq-topic-link anchorLink" href="#myAnchor">
<span class="topic_ questionTitle">FAQ Question</span>
</a>
</li>
</ul>


<ul class="aAnswers">
<li class="li_answers">
<a name="myAnchor" id="myAnchor"></a>
<span class="topic-head" id="topics_">FAQ Question</span>
Lorim Ipsum ...
<div class="back-to-top">
<a href="#faqtop" class="anchorLink">Back To Top</a></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The problem presents itself when I try to use the above html code elsewhere on the page ... like this:

```
<div id="container2">
    <ul class="Questions">
    <li class="anchorLink" href="#myAnchor">
    <a class="faq-topic-link anchorLink" href="#myAnchor">
    <span class="topic_ questionTitle">FAQ Question</span>
    </a>
    </li>
    </ul>


    <ul class="aAnswers">
    <li class="li_answers">
    <a name="myAnchor" id="myAnchor"></a>
    <span class="topic-head" id="topics_">FAQ Question</span>
    Lorim Ipsum ...
    <div class="back-to-top">
    <a href="#faqtop" class="anchorLink">Back To Top</a></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

I thought I was doing it properly by using "this" so the script would look to animate "this" container.

Comment: What exactly does _"they get confused"_ mean?

Comment: What's the different between this two HTML?

Comment: You also have JS grammar errors that you don't put `;` at the end of each statement.

Comment: @Sparky672 - By "confused" I mean that is I click on a list item in the second div it animates back to the first div.

Comment: @steven.yang: JavaScript doesn't require semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your html it looks like that might be the code that's causing you problems. Typically `href` properties in `<a></a>` tags are used for navigating to a unique id. Now the `id` property on html elements should be unique. It should be noted that anchor tags do not have to navigate to another anchor. They can navigate to any uniquely id'd element. Although if there are two elements with the same id then the navigation will go to the first matching id in the DOM.

From the given html both anchor tags have the same id. If you make those ids unique then I think you will see the result that you want. Maybe something like:

```
<a name="myAnchor" id="myAnchor" href="#navigateFromFirstAnchor">Go to First Div</a>
<div id="navigateFromFirstAnchor"></div>

<a name="mySecondAnchor" id="mySecondAnchor" href="#navigateFromSecondAnchor">Go To Second Div</a>
<div id="navigateFromSecondAnchor"></div>
```

See documentation for id attribute [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp) and anchor tag [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp).